# $Ch_A =(x+1)^6(x-2)^3 $ y $min_A = (x+1)^3(x-2)^2 $, List the possible Jordan forms for $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be a complex matrix such that $Ch_A =(x+1)^6(x-2)^3 $ y $min_A = (x+1)^3(x-2)^2  $, List the possible  Jordan forms for $A$. And in each case write the corresponding rational

I do not know if I'm wrong, but the possible Jordan forms are the intermediate polinomials.

$(x+1)^4(x-2)^2, (x+1)^5(x-2)^2, (x+1)^6(x-2)^2, (x+1)^4(x-2)^3,(x+1)^5(x-2)^3$

Answer (score 1):

Jordan Forms are matrices, not polynomials.

Deciding on the JCF is the same as deciding on which Jordan blocks to use.  And you already know a few facts about those:

1. You need to have Jordan blocks corresponding to the two eigenvalues of your matrix ($-1$ and $2$).
2. The sizes of your $-1$ Jordan blocks need to sum to $6$, and the sizes of the $2$ Jordan blocks need to sum to $3$ (because these are their multiplicities as roots of the characteristic polynomial).
3. The largest $-1$ block has size 3, and the largest $2$ block has size $2$ (because these are their multiplicities as roots of the minimal polynomial).

Any combination of blocks that satisfies these three conditions could potentially be a JCF for the matrix you describe.

So, for instance, you could have $2$-blocks of sizes $2$ and $1$, and $(-1)$-blocks of sizes $3$ and $2$.  This would correspond to a JCF of
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c|ccc|cc}
2&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&2&0&0&0&0&0&0\\\hline
0&0&2&0&0&0&0&0\\\hline
0&0&0&-1&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&-1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&-1&0&0\\\hline
0&0&0&0&0&0&-1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&-1
\end{array}\right].
$$
(Bars added to emphasize the blocks.)

Can you see how to list all configurations in terms of the sizes of $2$-blocks and $(-1)$-blocks?  As a hint, the only possible configurations for the $2$-blocks is to have a block of size $2$ and a block of size $1$.